# Negative-lookahead exclude exactly the given combination

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using the following regex

```
@"(?![iv][iv]?[i]?)(?![.])\b[a-z]+(['-][a-z]+)*[a-z]+\b"
```

to match a word that meets the following criteria:

1. Has 2 char or more (`[a-z]+(['-][a-z]+)*[a-z]+`, the stuff in parentheses allow for hyphenated/apostrophe'd words)
2. Has no periods in them `(?![.])` (e.g., Ph.D.)
3. Is not a word that contains the Roman numerals I or V (`(?![iv][iv]?[i]?)`) (e.g., VII)

It works well in general, but if one of the words is, say, `Vivian`, it will exclude that word. It appears that `Vivian` is excluded because it is a word with the characters I and V.  I want to program a negative-lookahead that will only exclude words composed of ONLY I and/or V, like III or VII or V. How can I make negative-lookahead less greedy?

Comment: With `?![.]` you are not matching the `.` but rather any character. `.` is a wildcard that matched anything. You need to use `(?![\.])`

Comment: @rae1 Unless the C# RegEx engine differs from most major RegEx flavors, while inside the square brackets most (if not all) keywords, including `.`, are literal.

Comment: Well, [C# regex engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) differs from most major regex flavors ;)

Comment: @rae1: Every regex flavor has its quirks, but `[.]` matches a literal dot in .NET just like it does in every other flavor I know of.

Answer (score 2):

This is your regex:

```
(?:
   [a-zABE-HJ-KNOQ-UWYZ'-]  # Any char from the previous list is allowed except C,D,I,L,M,P,V and X
 | [CDILVX](?![IVXLCDM]+\b) # C,D,I,L,V and X allowed if not part of a roman numeral
 | M(?!r?s?\.|D\b)  # M is allowed if not part of Mr., Ms., Mrs. or roman numeral MD
 | P(?!h\.D\.)      # P is allowed if not part of Ph.D.
){2,}
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/nP8kO2

#### Discussion

Since you're using `C#`, you can take advantage of [character class substraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) by replacing  in the above regex `[a-zABE-HJ-KNOQ-UWYZ'-]` with `[-'a-zA-Z-[CDILMPVX]]`. Thanks to [@Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling).

See it in action on [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=c047dd5d-be95-4c3c-98d5-1791729f8f71) (online regex tester for .NET).

This regex is sensible to its context. For instance, does the word `DIV` refers to the number **504** in roman numerals or the **div** html tag ? For now, the regex will reject `DIV` because it has a fordidden sequence: `IV`.

#### References

- [Using Personal Titles #4](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/using_personal_titles04.html)
- [Roman Numeral Converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/roman_numerals_advanced.htm)
- [Roman Numeral Chart](http://literacy.kent.edu/Minigrants/Cinci/romanchart.htm)

Comment: Neat job! I'd up the answer a few more times, if I could. Btw, thanks for the link to the regex tester. I'be been looking for a site like that since I ditched diapers. Kudos.

Comment: The meat and potatoes of the regex is inside a non-capturing block. My limited understanding of non-capturing blocks is that nothing inside that block is selected. Yet...the regex tester seems to match the logic inside the non-capturing block. Could you please explain how that works?

Comment: I unchecked this question because period terminated words, like `Mr.` or `Ms.` etc. are not excluded. Left the up-vote, because it does a great job on everything else.

Comment: @Seabiscuit I have updated my answer for excluding english titles like `Mr.` and others.

Comment: It might be nicer to use [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) for the first, big character class.

Comment: @Rawling Thanks for your optimization, I have updated my answer accordingly (see Discussion part). Your comment makes me discover RegexHero (http://regexhero.net/tester/) at the same time ;)

Comment: @Alex Again, impressive effort. This version takes care of _most_ of my situations. However, point 2 in my question requires a general expression for ANY word that may be an abbreviation, (E.g `Mrs.`). However, that may be my fault not yours. I failed to mention that I know I won't need the last word in the sentence, so ANY words with periods are useless to me. This is unrelated, but will make a HUGE difference in the regex, I'm using the regex option IngnoreCase!